# How to remove the fold level numbers in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin, vim-folding

I'm using NeoVIM, and I set up it to show folds automatically. The trouble is that when there is more than one level of folds, it's going to show numbers at the left.
[image]

Is there any way to remove them, just look like any other modern editors?

I searched on google, StackOverflow, and checked the [vimhelp page](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html). I haven't seen a way for this.

I'm sure that's the default behavior, I can reproduce it on the default vim of codesandbox and without any plugin. Please check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tereshkova-vwh5im?file=/README.md. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @j1-lee, thanks for your reply. However, I'm sure it's the default behavior. I've updated the description above. Please check.

Comment: "just look like any other modern editors?" Well, neither Vim nor Vim are "modern editors".

Comment: Are you using nvim-ufo to show the nice foldings? Anyway, this behavior is hard-coded into vim/neovim, current there is not option to change, see also [this issue](https://github.com/kevinhwang91/nvim-ufo/issues/4).

Comment: @jdhao, yes, I'm using nvim-ufo. Thanks for your information, I'll check that issue.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in `:help fold-foldcolumn`, when the value of `:help 'foldcolumn` is large enough, the fold level is indicated by vertical bars but, when there is not enough room, numbers are used instead. That behavior is not governed by any option so there is nothing you can do about it except rolling up your sleeves and modifying the source code.

That said, the `ˇ`s in your screenshot are clearly not standard `:help 'fillchars', as hinted in the comments, so you should probably take a look at what is redefining those before taking any action.

Answer (score 1):

put these in your rc file.

##### vimscript:

```
set foldcolumn 0
```

##### lua

```lua
vim.opt.foldcolumn = '0'
```

if it still doesn't work, then verify the value is `0` by `:set foldcolumn`.
If it is not `0`, it might be because you are overriding the value in your config somewhere.

###### HINT:

some plugins suggest setting the value to 1, thus if you copied their suggested config, the issue might be there.

Edit: this will also make them unclickable, so might not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still looks for an asnwer, this configuration in `luukvbaal/statuscol.nvim` solves the issue. I tested it myself.

```
  {
    'luukvbaal/statuscol.nvim',
    opts = function()
      local builtin = require('statuscol.builtin')
      return {
        setopt = true,
        -- override the default list of segments with:
        -- number-less fold indicator, then signs, then line number & separator
        segments = {
          { text = { builtin.foldfunc }, click = 'v:lua.ScFa' },
          { text = { '%s' }, click = 'v:lua.ScSa' },
          {
            text = { builtin.lnumfunc, ' ' },
            condition = { true, builtin.not_empty },
            click = 'v:lua.ScLa',
          },
        },
      }
    end,
  }
```